# Combine message menu and message button in slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to combine message menu and message button in my slack app.This is the workflow I am trying to achieve.

> 1) User fires a slack slash command to display the menu. This menu will have one dropdown and three buttons. This I am able to achieve.
>
> 2) I want user to select an option from dropdown and press any of the action button.Then only the action should be triggered

Problem is that when i select any option from dropdown, it triggers the action. I do not want the action to be triggered this way. I just want the action to be triggered after clicking on the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible with Slack. Clicking an option in an interactive menu will always issue an action.

Instead I would suggest to implement the workflow in two steps. First show the buttons and then the menu (or other way around).

Comment: @SCoder if this answer helped you, please consider marking it as solution, so we can close this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

https://api.slack.com/docs/message-menus

You can mix message buttons and message menus within the same message by including multiple attachments

Comment: If you could add more high level details in your answer it would be perfect in case if the article from the link will be removed.