# Get selected values from message menu or drop-down on click of a button in a slack interactive message or attachment

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api, botkit, slack-commands

I have a slack message with two actions:

1. Message Menu, i.e. dropdown
2. Button

---

I would like to:

1. Select a value from the message menu or drop-down.
2. Click the button.
3. On clicking this button, I would like to get the value of the selected value from the drop-down

---

Please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: Hi! Welcome To Stack Overflow. The question you are asking has already been asked. I will link it for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine message menu and message button in slack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304590/combine-message-menu-and-message-button-in-slack)